# Why is java.exe not visible from cygwin, but is visible from command-prompt?

Tags: windows-8, command-line, cygwin

Why can't I see java.exe from Cygwin?

[image: Cygwin vs Win8]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In x64 editions of Windows 8/7/Vista, contents of C:\Windows\System32 folder depend on the **bitness** of the application .

For 64-bit applications (such as Windows Command Prompt, `cmd.exe`) there's no filesystem redirection:
`C:\Windows\System32` (in software) -> `C:\Windows\System32` (on disk).
So, C:\Windows\System32 folder contains 64-bit DLL and EXE files, from the point-of-view of 64-bit application.

For 32-bit applications (such as `bash.exe` from Cygwin) which runs via WoW64 subsystem on Windows x64, there are two redirections in the filesystem:
`C:\Windows\System32` (in software) -> `C:\Windows\SysWOW64` (on disk).
`C:\Windows\Sysnative` (in software) -> `C:\Windows\System32` (on disk).
So, C:\Windows\System32 folder contains 32-bit DLL and EXE files, from the point-of-view of 32-bit application.

If you want to access 64-bit applications and DLL files (such as `java*.exe`) from 32-bit applications (such as Cygwin's `bash.exe`), you need to use `C:\Windows\Sysnative` path, or `/cygdrive/c/Windows/Sysnative` in Cygwin notation.

(this is an updated and extended answer)

Comment: Yes, they are there: Chloe@xps /cygdrive/c/Windows/sysnative
$ ls -la java*
-rwx------+ 1 SYSTEM SYSTEM 188320 Mar  7 04:43 java.exe

Comment: Why does it do that? I can't see sysnative from DOS prompt.

Comment: So, cygwin's bash.exe runs as 32-bit application and in that context C:\Windows\System32 is mapped to C:\Windows\SysWOW64 (a folder without java* files). Windows command prompt (cmd.exe) runs as 64-bit application and so it is able to see true C:\Windows\System32. Use C:\Windows\sysnative to access true system32 directory from 32-bit applications. More information on this topic: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384187%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: Wow that is totally backwards and confusing!

Comment: Yes, they should have made \Windows\system64 directory for 64-bit system DLL and EXE files, but unfortunately we have 64-bit files in System32 directory and awkward filesystem redirection.